# Protractor screenshot tests error code 105

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

Protractor tests were running well till I messed around with my `config.js` file to include screenshot testing.

Errors from running **protractor conf.js**

> C:\Users\hhhhhh\mmmm\tests\e2e>protractor conf.js
>
> [10:50:13] E/configParser - error code: 105
>
> [10:50:13] E/configParser - description: failed loading configuration file conf.js
>
> C:\Users\hhhhhh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js:130
>               throw new exitCodes_1.ConfigError(logger, 'failed loading configuration file ' + filename);`

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "e2e",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "yup yup yup",
  "main": "conf.js",
  "dependencies": {
  "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.3.1",
  "protractor": "3.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**conf.js**

```
  var ScreenShotReporter = require('protractor-screenshot-reporter');

  exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    capabilities: {
      'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

    directConnect: true,

    framework: 'jasmine2',

    specs: ['specs/*spec.js'],

    onPrepare: function() {
       jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new ScreenShotReporter({
          baseDirectory: 'target/screenshots'
       }));
    }

  };
```

Many seem to be having issues with this. Anyone found a sound solution?

Comment: can you paste your config file?

Comment: @igniteram1 `conf.js` added

Comment: where have you defined the ```saveScreenshot``` ?

Comment: @igniteram1 sorry it's been edited again after tweaking around. We disagreed with the previous  `saveScreenshot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks from your `package.json` that you are using `protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter` but you are using `protractor-screenshot-reporter` in your `conf.js`. Both are different modules, please use one of those and try again!

Comment: Well isn't this why we love dev.. Got to savor such embarrassing moments!!.. Thanks! Works perfect now.

Comment: I understand, Glad it helped you :)